# Can font sizes be changed in C (in the shell)?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, fonts

I'm writing a C program out of the shell (Macintosh Terminal, to be specific), and would like to know if you can change font sizes within the program so it would look like:

## Hello world!

#### Hello world!

Thanks!

P.S. The question isn't platform-specific. I'd love to hear if this is possible on another platform.

Comment: Actually, this is platform specific. For starters, you can only have a single font size in the Terminal. Of course, you can change the entire sizes, but not for an individual line.  There is no escape sequence to change the Terminal character size. However, you can do it with AppleScript.  I can assure you that it's different on OSX than on Windows than on Linux

Comment: An interesting question if you're exploring the history of computer display devices. But if you're really interested in output as you have  included in your example, the modern solution is to use software that is designed to display different size fonts this assumes either a windowing system that can manage fonts, ie. MS Widoze or XWindows (probably others) OR that you go with 90% of the world, and use html in a browser.  (Terminal windows are not one of those systems, excepting R's mention of dbl-size terminal fonts. I guess it would be possible to write your own terminal prog.) Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

In general, terminals do not support varying the font. Very faithful emulators of some of the VT100-family terminals may provide double-width and/or double-height font mode (you may have seen these modes used on some old green- or orange-screen retail cash register terminals), but I think they're unlikely to be supported on modern terminal emulators.

Comment: To find out for sure, `perl -le 'print "\033#3hello\n\033#4hello"'`. It still works in xterm!

Comment: You sir just rocked my world!

Comment: dead on gnome terminal 3.4.1.1 ='(

Answer (score 1):

Although you cannot generally change the font size, there are ways to mimic that with ASCII art.  Look at some FIGlet servers which use ASCII art fonts to generate text to get ideas.  Here's the first one I found on Google:  http://patorjk.com/software/taag/#p=display&f=Graffiti&t=Type%20Something

There are many different fonts in many different sizes, but here's some example

```
_________ _______          _________
\__   __/(  ____ \|\     /|\__   __/
   ) (   | (    \/( \   / )   ) (   
   | |   | (__     \ (_) /    | |   
   | |   |  __)     ) _ (     | |   
   | |   | (       / ( ) \    | |   
   | |   | (____/\( /   \ )   | |   
   )_(   (_______/|/     \|   )_(
```

It's not too hard to go from there to embedding one of the fonts into your program and using it to display whatever you want.